# Fatal error: Class 'WPGradeOptions' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just put the theme on `C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes`.

When I logged in my WP account and activate the theme its give the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'WPGradeOptions' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\ROSA\rosa\wpgrade-core\bootstrap.php on line 40

Comment: go to this line and see how the code initates the WPGradeOptions class. The class file should be included in bootstrap.php

Comment: the Code is this wpgrade::options_handler( new WPGradeOptions() );

Comment: in your boostrap.php at the top do `include 'WPGradeOptions.php` or whatever is the file name in which this class resides.